# Transpose Oracle table/data set

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I need some input/help on transposing my table:

```
Key | ATTR_NAME | ATTR_VALUE
1234|  SS_VALUE |  SENSITIVE 
1234|  XX_VALUE |   4456
```

After transposing it, I would like my output to look like:

```
Key | SS_VALUE | XX_VALUE
1234| SENSITIVE|  4456
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is only about 2 cols transpose then conditional aggregation might help you -

```
SELECT Key
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN ATTR_NAME = 'SS_VALUE' THEN ATTR_VALUE END) SS_VALUE 
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN ATTR_NAME = 'XX_VALUE' THEN ATTR_VALUE END) XX_VALUE
FROM T
GROUP BY Key
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using a query including `pivot` keyword, since what you need is pivoting  :

```
select *
  from
  ( select * from tab )
  pivot
  (
   max(attr_value) for attr_name in ( 'SS_VALUE' as ss_value, 'XX_VALUE' as xx_value )
  );
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cfeb39e73b9dd00d9f2250a22540bcc9)</kbd>